# How to get src of an image like this?

Tags: javascript

```
<div data-layer="">
  <div class="area-comment-left">
    <a class="thumb" target="_blank" href="index.php">
      <img class="avatar" src="1.jpg" data-name="www">
    </a>
  </div>
</div>
<a href="">GO</a>
```

and above,the value of data-layer is a number which user inputs,and there are multiple data-layers,so you can only get the image by which user inputs:

```
<input class="floor" value="a number">
```

then how to change the href of "a" to the src of image? like this:

`<a href="1.jpg">GO</a>`
maybe this will work?

```
var floor = $("div[data-layer="+$('.floor').val()"] .area-comment-left .thumb .avatar").attr("src");
```

Thank you very much for your help!

Comment: the same way you decided that `1.jpg` should be in the image src.

Comment: So, basically you want to get every `.thumb` and set it's `href` to the `src` of the image inside of it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`$('.thumb').attr('href', '1.jpeg'); //JQuery`

or

`var a = document.getElementsByTagName('a')[0].href = "1.jpeg";`

With user input:

```
<form action="" method="POST">
    <input type="text" id="txtImage"/>
    <input type="button" id="cmdOk" value="Ok"/>
</form>//could be a div but for the purpose I decided I would use a form
<script>
    $('#cmdOk').on('click', function(){ $('.thumb').attr('href', $('#txtImage').val());});
</script>
```

Comment: The method name is `getElement*s*ByTagName`, and it returns not one element, but a live NodeList. See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element.getElementsByTagName

Comment: there are multiple data-layers,so you can only get the image by which user inputs,then how to do that?

Comment: @PSL sorry for the *s* was a typo.

Comment: @Sebastien Even now it won't do what op wants. Since even with the snippet provided `a[0]` will be `<a class="thumb" target="_blank" href="index.php">`

Comment: what can I do if I can only get the href by what user inputs?

Comment: replace '1.jpeg' by the variable that contains the user input.

Comment: I mean what user inputs is a number of data-layer's value

Answer (score 0):

You must fetch the image src attribute first and then assing it to the a's href:

```
var image_src = $('.avatar').attr('src')

$('.thumb').attr('href', image_src);
```

or using plain javascript

```
var image = document.querySelector('.avatar');
var a = document.querySelector('.thumb');

a.href = image.src;
```

Comment: what can I do if I can only get href of the image by what user inputs?

Comment: Please explain more about what that means.  How is the user inputting?

Comment: If the user can select an image, you wouldn't be able to access to the local image's path. If you refer that the user can use an image's url, the method would be similar but getting the 'src' attribute from an input instead. Please explain more :)

Comment: I mean what user inputs is a number of data-layer's value :)

Answer (score 0):

```
var thumbs=document.getElementsByClassName('thumb');
  // loop through the `.thumb`s
for(var i=0,l=thumbs.length;i<l;i++){
    thumbs[i].href=thumbs[i].getElementsByClassName('avatar')[0].src;
}
```

This will loop through all the `.thumb`s and set their `href` to the `src` of the `.avatar` image element inside them.

Comment: I mean what user inputs is a number of data-layer's value

Comment: The a element that he wants to change is outside form the '.thumb' scope